# Access JavaScript variable using HTMLUnit

Tags: java, javascript, html, htmlunit

How can I get value from JavaScript variable using `HTMLUnit` framework? Like I have `var important = "Few important words"` and I want to get this string.

Answer (score 3):

If the variable is globall-scoped, I would try using the [`executeJavaScript(...)`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#executeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) function.

But if the variable is not globally-scopes, I think you're out of luck:

```
(function(){
    var important = "Few important words";
    // ...
}());
```

In that case you may have to rely on screen-scraping or actually parsing the HTML/JavaScript to extract the information. Good luck.

See also [How do I extract a long string of text from some JavaScript on a web page using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113552/how-do-i-extract-a-long-string-of-text-from-some-javascript-on-a-web-page-using) - that question is about Python, but the final answer - "use regular expressions" - seems like it could work in Java. [Parsing HTML/JavaScript with a RegEx is not the ideal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/248129), but if you have no other options...

Comment: I see, but when I use `System.out.println(page.executeJavaScript("mobile").toString());` I get `ScriptResult[result=null page=HtmlPage(*url deleted by me*)@1990889081]`. What should I do? While executing `alert(window["mobile"]);` in Google Chrome there is window with correct value.
BTW. It is an object, I didn't mention it before.

Comment: The return type of `executeJavaScript(...)` is [`ScriptResult`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/ScriptResult.html). Read the API for `ScriptResult`! Maybe `getJavaScriptResult().toString()` will give better results.

Comment: .toString() represents whole object as string so value is "null" which means nothing. Sadly using `getJavaScriptResult` doesn't help either.

Comment: I take it `mobile` is the variable you're trying to access? Perhaps `page.executeJavaScript("return mobile").getJavaScriptResult().toString()` - I would assume that in order for `getJavaScriptResult` to return a non-null value the JS snippet has to return a value.

Comment: Using `System.out.println(page.executeJavaScript("return mobile").getJavaScriptResult());` gives "null" in console. With `.toString()` I get NullPointerException. And yes, mobile is boolean variable (I'm trying to get value from simple type first, then I will play with object one).

Comment: @wirher : Could you resolve your problem then ? I am trying to get the result of a var, which is json to save the json. No chance. Thx for a quick response.

Comment: @mmx73 Actually I used regex to extract data I wanted back then.